# How to include array of objects into Mongoose during save()?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an array of objects that need to be inserted into new document when doing Modal.save(). What will be the best practise to achieve this?

How can I insert this:

```
var array = [
  { "id" : "001", "itemName" : "itemName001" },
  { "id" : "002", "itemName" : "itemName002" },
]
```

into this:

```
var newItemCollection = new Collection ({
    collectionName: req.body.collectionName,
    items: [
         { id : array.id, itemName: array.itemName, itemDescription: "Foo was here..." }
    ]
});
newItemCollection.save();
```

So it will return something like this:

```
{
   "collectionName" : "Collection A",
   "items" : [
              { "id" : "001", "itemName" : "itemName001", "itemDescription" : "Foo was here..." },
              { "id" : "002", "itemName" : "itemName002", "itemDescription" : "Foo was here..." },
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly call `create` function of mongoose,

```
 var array = [
  { "id" : "001", "itemName" : "itemName001" },
  { "id" : "002", "itemName" : "itemName002" },
]

var items = [] 

array.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry['itemDescription'] = "Foo was here..."
    items.push(entry)
});

var data = {
    collectionName: req.body.collectionName,
    items: items
}


 Collection.create(data, function (err, res) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('saved')
})
```

Comment: Should that not be `items: array` And looks like a `.map()` should be called for the `itemDescription`